# How can I install the qtree package?

Tags: qtree

I want to draw trees in my document. After downloading the `qtree.sty` file and place it input the working folder, but when I add this: `\usepackage{qtree}`, LaTeX still complaint:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pict2e.sty' not found.
```

But I do not know where to find `pict2e.sty` and how to install it.

Is there a better way to install `qtree`, instead of downloading the file manually? (I am using Ubuntu)

**EDIT**
I have done this job by searching the package of qtree in synaptic package manager.

Comment: `pict2e`is part of `pgf`. Using Ubuntu I guess you use TeX Live. I fear you installed with `apt-get` and do not have the package manager, what would make it very simple for you to install mising packages from CTAN. Take a look on [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) an also [TeX Live 2011 vs Ubuntu TeX Live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60589/tex-live-2011-vs-ubuntu-tex-live). (I am a MiKTeX user, so cannot specifically help.)

Comment: @Speravir looks great to me (as an Ubuntu user), particularly the vanilla link :)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/86

Comment: `pict2e` is not in fact part of `pgf` : `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty`.  But independent of this, I would recommend you use `tikz-qtree` instead of `qtree`.

Comment: Alan Munn is right, I unfortunately misread something.

Comment: @UniMouS We will need to know something about your set up to give info on installing `pict2e`. What operating system and TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: I am using ubuntu, and live tex

Comment: have you followed the instructions in the links from the first comment? please confirm :)

Comment: Here is how I install qtree package in Ubuntu TeX Live: http://alstatr.blogspot.com/2014/02/latex-how-to-install-tex-live-qtree.html

Comment: To extend an existing Latex installation on  Ubuntu: `sudo apt install texlive-humanities` (works for me on Ubuntu 20.04)