# Uninstalling STIX Fonts

Tags: fonts, installing, ubuntu, mathjax, stix

I recently installed the `texlive-full` package, and want to uninstall the STIX fonts because they are interfering with my MathJax rendering. What is the terminal command to uninstall them? (I'm using Linux Mint 15, and pulled TL from the Ubuntu/Mint package repositories.)

I'm asking because I don't want to mess up any dependencies, and am trying to uninstall them as cleanly as possible.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but wouldn't it be easier to configure MathJax so that it ignores them?

Comment: I don't think so, actually. Remember that uninstalling STIX should only take a one-line "Sudo apt-get uninstall ...".

Comment: So you are using a Debian derivative? And you installed TL using apt-get? That is, you did not install the version provided by upstream directly but used your package manager? I ask because nobody can answer your question without more details. There are numerous versions of GNU/Linux. My distro does not use apt-get, for example (and I didn't use the package manager to install TL in any case). So what might work for me would not work on your system. Linux is *just* the kernel. Every distro is different.

Comment: Yes, I installed texlive-full using apt-get, i.e. I installed the version provided by the package manager.

Comment: Well, btw, I recommend uninstalling `texlive-full` and installing it from the oficial TeX webpages. The one in your distro is always outdated. [More info on this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) and [some propaganda info](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60589/tex-live-2011-vs-ubuntu-tex-live).

Comment: Uninstalling some small part of TeXlive isn't as simple as it sounds. Just ask about the MathJaX on StackOverflow and you'll get an answer. The MathJaX maintainer follows SO and will answer you.

Comment: If MathJax is using stix then if you haven't got them it'll make them available as web fonts so the rendering should be the same, but slower if you uninstall local stix. So there seems to be a problem with your mathjax setup

Comment: As an alternative you could install the MathJax fonts, which MathJax will prefer over STIX when both are installed. Most debian derivatives have a package for them.

Comment: @tohecz Maybe I'm missing something, but the links you provide don't say anything about uninstalling ``texlive-full``? I'm considering moving to Ubuntu, and I'm really blown away by how incredibly complicated it seems to be to install texlive ...

Comment: @Sverre You don't need to uninstall `texlive-full`, but what's the purpose of having two TeX distros in parallel?

Comment: @yo' The texlive distributions are not nearly as far behind on e.g. ubuntu as they used to be.  Going through the packaging system has other benefits.

Answer (score 1):

When I was trying to use `otf` fonts within TeXLive, I copied the file below to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and then I run `sudo fc-cache`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
  <fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

After that, I had the same problem.

**Solution (works for me)**

I just moved that file, run `sudo fc-cache` again, and then everything is fine like before.